# How to pass paymentIntent to my app use SiriKit on payment?

Tags: ios, payment, sirikit

Can **SiriKit** pass the **INSendPaymentIntent** to my app? The intent has to be handled by my app, instead of in the Siri extension. But the INSendPaymentIntentResponse does not have the .**continueInApp** like INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCode. There is .failureRequiringAppLaunch, but that behavior is not the preferred one. Have any idea? How to pass object to my app ?

Answer (score 1):

In IntentHandler Extension, there is a handle method which works when user clicks "Send" button in Siri UI Extension. (Swift 3, iOS 10 and 11)

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INSendPaymentIntentHandling {

    func handle(intent: INSendPaymentIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendPaymentIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        if let _ = intent.payee, let currencyAmount = intent.currencyAmount {
            // Handle the payment here!

            // Create a user activity to pass it to our application
            let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType:"myActivityName")

            // Pass parameter dictionary to the userinfo  
            userActivity.userInfo = ["amount": Int(truncating: currencyAmount.amount!)] 

            // By providing a userActivity to the intent response, Siri will open up the app and continue the payment there
            completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse.init(code: .inProgress, userActivity: userActivity))
        }
    }
}
```

After that continueUserActivity is called in our application

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
    // Parse userActivity.userInfo parameter to get the amount etc.

    return YES;
}
```